# Nivo Slider - Position navigation bullets at bottom of slider, rather than underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I'm making a website and have used Nivo Slider to create a jQuery slider.

I'm having an issue with the bullets used to show which slide the user is viewing. I would like the bullets to appear on the images of the slider, rather than below.

I managed to move the bullets to the location using the following CSS code:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    top: 365px;
    z-index:3000 !important;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    display:block;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(../images/banner/dots.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:left;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of how they should look:
http://i41.tinypic.com/mt59gi.png

But once I resize the browser window, the bullets move off the slider, like this: http://i40.tinypic.com/2ldtus8.png

I've changed top: 365px; to a percentage too, but that seemed to produce the same result.

Is there any way to keep the bullets on the slider, even when the browser window is resized? The slider width is 100%, so the slider will also resize with the browser window. Preferably, I'd like to keep it that way, if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: I've posted a test version to www.fearless-music.net/test/**

Comment: Is your image resizing when the browser is being resized?

Comment: @MatthewWoodard - It is resizing too. I've set the width of the slider to be 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the width of the image is changing when the browser is resized then more than likely so is the height.

In this case if the height is changing your code "top: 365px;" becomes irrelevant.

IMO I would adjust the distance from the top of the wrapper with a media query ... Something like so:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    top: 365px;
    z-index:3000 !important;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {

.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    top: 265px;
    z-index:3000 !important;
}

}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    top: 165px;
    z-index:3000 !important;
}

}

@media (max-width: 400px) {

.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    top: 65px;
    z-index:3000 !important;
}

}
```

I would be best to see what break points you are trying to compensate for and see what the height of the image changes to, then determine the necessary value for "top" in your css.

More info [here](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design).

Comment: Thanks for your help! It sort of works now. The bullets have disappears and have been replaced by numbers until the window is resized to a smaller size?

I've uploaded my entire CSS code to JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r97tU/

Comment: Instead of the bullets appearing, numbers appear until the window is resized to a smaller size. Once the window is resized back to a larger size, the numbers will re-appear, replacing the bullets.

Comment: Your fiddle is not displaying for me ... do you have a link I could view?

Comment: I've just uploaded it to [http://www.fearless-music.net/test](http://www.fearless-music.net/test) I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can't really do much with out any relevant code, but I can tell you what ever is containing `.nivo-controlNav` needs to have `position: relative` that way the bullets will stay confined within that area.

Comment: I changed it to relative, like you suggested, but it didn't work - it made the bullets move to the very bottom of the page. Thanks anyway.

Comment: what did you change to relative? Can you post more code, again, it's hard to help with out seeing the issue

Comment: `.nivo-controlNav {
 text-align:center;
 padding: 15px 0;
 position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -50px;
 top: 365px;
 z-index:3000 !important;
}`